# setting foreign key to display only the users info

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

how can I show logged in user only his info under My Account link that I have in my page? I tried setting a foreign key between two tables cos I have the one table for the login and the another one for the inserting photo, info stuff and to associate the author of the photo to a username which I have in a table `users`. My aim is to show only the user info and photo of logged in user.

The problem is when I try to set the foreign key it sets the foreign key but the data doesn't get in to the table. On the page where I Upload the picture and insert some info it shows me that the uploaded succeed but when I go and see in my database there is nothing. any help? I'm stuck at this for long time.

Here is what I did to create the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
`password` varchar(40) default NULL,
`usersalt` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`userid` varchar(32) default NULL,
`userlevel` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) default NULL,
`timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`actkey` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`regdate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos (
ref int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    photo varchar(75),
Firstname varchar(35),
    Lastname varchar(35),
    Age INT(3),
    author varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ref)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

here is what I tried to add FK after creating the table..

```
ALTER TABLE photos
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_photos
FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES users(username)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Finally here is my Upload.php

```
<?php
include("/include/session.php");
if(!$session->logged_in){ header("Location: ../main.php"); } else {
}
?>
<?php
$sub=0;

ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) {
// your save code goes here

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "";
if (file_exists("pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "<font size='4' color='red'><b>We are sorry, the file you trying to upload already exists.</b></font>";
  }

else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$sub= 1;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "secure_login");

// TODO - Check that connection was successful.

$photo= "pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$age   =$_POST["age"];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (photo, Firstname, Lastname, Age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $photo, $fname, $lname, $age);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();



echo "<font size='7' color='white'><b> Success! Your Photo has been Uploaded.</b></font>";
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=home.php">';
}

}
}
else
{
echo "<font size='4' color='red'><b>We are sorry, the file you trying to upload is not an image or it exceeds 2MB in size.</b></font><br><font color='blue'><i>Only images under size of 2MB are allowed</i></font>.";
}
}


?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="submited" value="true" />


<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
if($sub==0)
{
?> 
<label  for="file"><font  size="5"><b>Choose Photo:</b></font></label>
<input id="shiny" type="file" name="file" onchange="file_selected = true;" required><br>
First Name:<input  type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['fname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']) : ''); ?>"required><br> 
Last Name:<input  type="text" name="lname" required><br> 
Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
<input id="shiny" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
<?php
}
?>


</form>
</div>
```

this is main.php page where It shows the usename when the user is logged in

```
if($session->logged_in){
echo "<h1>Logged In</h1>";
echo "<table border='1' width='100%' bgcolor='red'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Welcome <b>$session->username</b>, you are logged in. <br><br>"
   ."[<a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">My Account</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;"
   ."[<a href=\"useredit.php\">Edit Account</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
   echo "[<a href=\"upload.php\">Upload</a>]";
   echo "[<a href=\"test2.php\">My Uploads</a>]";



if($session->isAdmin()){
      echo "[<a href=\"admin/index.php\">Admin Center</a>] &nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }
   echo "[<a href=\"process.php\">Logout</a>]";
   }
   else{
   ?>
```

Comment: Nowhere in your query did you set the author field.

Comment: the reason why I did that was because I was reading how to set foreign key tutorial and followed what the tutorial says.. yes I didn't set author field..

Comment: The HTTP Location Header needs to be an absolute URL! header("Location: ../main.php"); as of RFC 2616 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to actually add the user id to the query:

```
$photo= "pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$age   =$_POST["age"];
$username = "?";//Add code here to get the username you are interested in
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (photo, Firstname, Lastname, Age, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $photo, $fname, $lname, $age,$username);
```

You don't show the code which grabs user info but assuming your current query is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'someUser';
```

You can change this to include the photo (the group by is in case a user can have multiple photos:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN photos p ON (p.author = u.username)
WHERE u.username = 'someUser'
GROUP BY u.username;
```

Comment: you put ? on $username, how I'm supposed to get the username who is logged in?

Comment: This depends entirely on your site. How do you usually get the details of the person who is logged in?

Comment: By the looks of things you can use: `$session->username` provided you get `$session` from the same place as main.php does.

Comment: i tried that but still nothing gets in..may there be any thing I have to change on photos table?

Comment: @Haymi Try using echoing '$stmt->error()' after executing to see what went wrong.

Comment: I'm discouraged. it doesn't seem to be working.. you know what when I set the author column to NULL the the data gets in there but any rows added to author column are shown as NULL I don't see any usernames being inserted..uffff I was trying the whole day to get this work but got nothing except tiredness.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed a constraint on `author` column and made it not null. It means that every record in `photos` table need to have `author` filled and value in this column must be present in `users` table in column `username`.

In your `INSERT` query you are not setting any value for `author` so it fail due to constrains and table definition (`NOT NULL`).

To make it work you have to ensure `author` column is always filled, or make it nullable to allow anonymous uploads.

Comment: so what I need is making author null? what value should I set for author on INSERT query?

Comment: I guess it would be username of logged in user who uploads the photo. And null it you allow not logged in to upload photos.

Comment: I think it would be simple if you show me how do I get the logged in username so that I can insert it along with the photo, Firstname, lastname..stuff. That was What I wanted at first.

Comment: I think showing ready to use solution is bad, since you don't understand what you are doing and you have no motivation to understand it. I was trying to explain what foreign keys are, encourage you to learn more about it and finally be able to fix it for yourself.

Comment: I agree with ya...I wish I could understand it the way you told me but I'm unable to achieve that. I have tried all the day but got nothing. If I were able to get it work the way you told me, I'd be happy but it didn't work for me.  I'm still stuck at this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `author` field in your insert.  Because of your foreign key constraint, any insert attempts that don't have this value will fail.

You also should be checking for and logging any MySQL errors.  If  you would have done so, you would already have known you the inserts fail because of a foreign key constraint.